# how does setenv and unsetenv change the stack?

Tags: c, linux, gnu

I'm reading a textbook on several functions for manipulating the environment array:

> *If the environment array contains a string of the form name=oldvalue, then
> unsetenv deletes it and setenv replaces oldvalue with newvalue, but only if
> overwrite is nonzero. If name does not exist, then setenv adds name=newvalue
> to the array*

```
int setenv(const char *name, const char *newvalue, int overwrite);

void unsetenv(const char *name);
```

and below is a picture that depicts the organization of the user stack when a new program starts.
[image]

My questions are:

Q1- let's say we use `unsetenv` delete one element of `envp`, isn't it going to create a gap in `envp` by replacing original value with `NULL`? since the value is `NULL`, any subsequent environment elements after it will be ingored?

Q2-if we use `setenv` to replace a oldvalue with newvalue, if the lengh of newvalue is greater than oldvalue, then it is not going to work if `setenv` just modify the exiting  section of "Null-terminated environment variable strings". So my guessing is, there will be a new element pushed to the stack, and the corrsponding pointer element in the `envp` wiill be changed accordingly, is my understanding correct?

Comment: "when a new program starts". Nobody said implementations can't move the location of the environment variables. Most implementations make a copy of the environment variables when manipulated via those APIs.

Comment: Here is [example source code](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/setenv.c.html#170) showing how the `__environ` can be reallocated and moved around.

Answer (score 2):

> below is a picture that depicts the organization of the user stack when a new program starts

That's correct but the assumption that the env APIs are restricted to manipulating just that memory is not correct. Implementations are free to make a copy of the environment variables and indeed most implementations do that. Here is an example of a libc implementation that does exactly that.

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdlib/setenv.c.html#__add_to_environ

```
/* This function is used by `setenv' and `putenv'.... */
__add_to_environ (const char *name, const char *value, const char *combined,
                  int replace)
{  
    ....
    new_environ = (char **) realloc (last_environ,
                                   (size + 2) * sizeof (char *));      
    ....
    if (__environ != last_environ)
        memcpy ((char *) new_environ, (char *) __environ,
                size * sizeof (char *));
    ....
    last_environ = __environ = new_environ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`setenv` and `unsetenv` are not part of the C standard; that standard only provides `getenv`, which "searches an environment list provided by the host environment", with no specification as to how that list is created. The functions for manipulating the environment list will be found in the Posix standard (and other places for implementations which don't pretend to conform to Posix).

Posix also specifies the global variable `environ`, which points to the current environment list. When `main()` is entered:

> the following variable, which must be declared by the user if it is to be used directly:
>
> ```
> extern char **environ;
> ```
>
> is initialized as a pointer to an array of character pointers to the environment strings.

As it happens, many operating systems put the initial environment list on the stack before calling `main()`, although this is not required by any standard. Moreover, the value of `environ` is not fixed:

> Applications can change the entire environment in a single operation by assigning the `environ` variable to point to an array of character pointers to the new environment strings.

But that freedom comes with a lot of caveats:

> After assigning a new value to `environ`, applications should not rely on the new environment strings remaining part of the environment, as a call to `getenv()`, `putenv()`, `setenv()`, `unsetenv()`, or any function that is dependent on an environment variable may, on noticing that `environ` has changed, copy the environment strings to a new array and assign `environ` to point to it.

Furthermore:

> Any application that directly modifies the pointers to which the `environ` variable points has undefined behavior.

In fact, some implementations do take advantage of that flexibility, so those warnings need to be taken into account. That makes it tricky to manage dynamic memory if you create your own `environ`, so you might have to take a relaxed attitude to possible memory leaks (although the standard library itself probably manages its own memory more carefully).

On a Linux or BSD system, you should be able to find out a lot more locally-specific information by using the `man environ` command; the Posix standard itself includes the information in the [description of the `exec*` interfaces](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html). Also worth reading is the "Rationale" section of the [`getenv()` description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getenv.html).

With fifty years of hindsight, it's easy to criticise this design. All the same, it has basically served the world pretty well, and it is so entrenched that it's hard to see how it can be changed. So like it or not, there it is.